# Behaviour of a mixture of ideal gases

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, gas

If we have a mixture of ideal gases can we consider the mixture also an ideal gas?

This holds true in air for example where we consider it an ideal gas, when oxygen and nitrogen are considered ideal.

But does this always hold true?

Comment: There's some interesting entropy during the mixing process but after it is thoroughly mixed and can be considered to have single unified values of pressure, temperature, volume, etc it should approximately hold.  Are you looking at the mixing stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A mixture of gases acts like a mix of each individual gas, not like a new entity.

So yes, it will still act like an ideal gas since it's just the total of all the ideal gases in the mixture.  For example, the total pressure of a mixture of gases is equal to the sum of each gas' partial pressure.

Note that some liquids act differently than this when mixed and form an azeotrope, which has different characteristics than its components, which is why water and alcohol will not stratify once mixed.